# Magento 1 Payment method not loading or showing on Checkout

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, payment-methods

After Magento version upgrade or installing patches, most of the we face problem "Payment method not loading after clicking CONTINUE button of shipping method step on Checkout page". What could be solution for it.

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution for it, we need to update on the layout. Change  template/checkout/onepage/payment.phtml and go to below line of code 36:

```
<fieldset>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('methods') ?>
</fieldset>
```

add id "checkout-payment-method-load" to fieldset, like:

```
<fieldset id="checkout-payment-method-load">
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('methods') ?>
</fieldset>
```

That's it, now your code should work. Keep in mind, you should not do it in the base package, instead do it in your own.